# how do I re-populate this zend form?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I have an issue where I cannot seem to get the values to re-populate the zend form. I am using the form a bit different that what I am used to.

I have broken the 'social security number' into three fields, the values come out as an array, but I cannot get them to go back in after the operation.

This is my form class:

```
class Application_Form_Checkssnforexistingreferral extends Zend_Form {
    public function init() {

        // SSN
        $this->addElement('text', 'ss_number', array(
                'label' => 'SSN: ',
                'required' => True,
        ));

    }
}
```

Then in my view I use the form like so...

```
<?php // SSN (first segment)
                            echo '<p>Social Security Number</p>';
                            echo $this->formText('ss_number["first"]', '', array(
                                'size' => 3, 
                                'maxlength' => 3,
                                'required' => True,
                                'id' => 'ssn1',
                                )) 
                            ?>
                        <span>-</span>
                        <?php // SSN (second segment) 
                            echo $this->formText('ss_number["second"]', '', array(
                                'size' => 2, 
                                'maxlength' => 2,
                                'required' => True,
                                'id' => 'ssn2',
                                )) 
                            ?>
                        <span>-</span>
                        <?php // SSN (third segment) 
                            echo $this->formText('ss_number["third"]', '', array(
                                'size' => 4, 
                                'maxlength' => 4,
                                'required' => True,
                                'id' => 'ssn3',
                                )) 
                            ?>
```

I did it like this so that I may have greater control over the styling and presentation of the form elements, it works quite well on a larger form, although I am having issues populating the fields on that one too.

Here is what I am attempting in the controller...

```
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            if ($form->isValid($formData)) {



                $referralsModel = new Application_Service_Findssninreferrals();
                $referrals = $referralsModel->findSocialSecurityNumber($formData);

                // load the view's parameter 'referral' w/ the object collection
                // and 'NULL' the 'first page load' parameter
                $this->view->referrals = $referrals;

                $first = $formData['ss_number']['"first"'];
                $second = $formData['ss_number']['"second"'];
                $third = $formData['ss_number']['"third"'];

                $form->populate(array('ss_number["first"]' => $first,
                                      'ss_number["second"]' => $second,
                                      'ss_number["third"]' => $third
                            ));
                if (empty($referrals)) {
                    $flashMessenger->addMessage('There is no record found for this SSN, you may create a new referral for this client');

                    print_r($formData);
                    $form->populate(array($formData['ss_number']));

                    $ssn = $first . $second . $third;
                    $this->view->continueLink = "link to create new referral" . $ssn;
                    } 

            } else {
                      // else populate the form and allow the correction of...
                      $flashMessenger->addMessage('There was a problem with the number that you entered, please try again...');
                      $form->populate($formData);
                   }

            }
            $this->view->form = $form;
```

...

this is how one of the elements renders as HTML...

```
<p>Social Security Number</p>
<input type="text" required="1" maxlength="3" size="3" value="" id="ssn1" name="first" class="idleField">
```

In the controller, the 'if(emtpy($referrals))' section is where I was doing most of the experimenting trying to get it to repopulate the fields. The section above does not work either, I basically attempted to just to a 'form->populate(array(...' but with no luck either. I am just not getting anything from the 'populate' method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try redirecting to the requesting url should take you right back with form populated. Otherwise this probably won't work, you can't populate the form without a request (could use ajax) and you don't have a new request after the post. This one action should probably be at least 2 actions, however
you can try it this way:

```
 if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            if ($form->isValid($formData)) {

                $referralsModel = new Application_Service_Findssninreferrals();
                $referrals = $referralsModel->findSocialSecurityNumber($formData);

                // load the view's parameter 'referral' w/ the object collection
                // and 'NULL' the 'first page load' parameter
                $this->view->referrals = $referrals;

                $first = $formData['ss_number']['"first"'];
                $second = $formData['ss_number']['"second"'];
                $third = $formData['ss_number']['"third"'];

                if (empty($referrals)) {
                    $flashMessenger->addMessage('There is no record found for this 
                        SSN, you may create a new referral for this client');

                    $this->_redirect($this->getRequest()->getRequestUri());
                    //next line may or may not be needed or help
                    $form->populate($formData);

                    $ssn = $first . $second . $third;
                    $this->view->continueLink = "link to create new referral" . $ssn;
                }
            } else {
                // else populate the form and allow the correction of...
                $flashMessenger->addMessage('There was a problem with the number that you entered, please try again...');
                $form->populate($formData);
            }
        }
        $this->view->form = $form;
```

Comment: My form is actually making a request to that URI when the submit button is clicked, if I do it like this then it would be the third request, leaving the var $formData empty as well. I think it has more to do with the $formData being a multi-dimensional array as it works if I just 'echo $form' and $form is three input boxes, which won't render the way I need it to though. But thanks much for your answer

Comment: @rhaag71 your first request displays the form, the second posts the form to the action, from this post you get the post data. You have to have another request to redisplay the form and populate the fields. Personally I would probably use a _forward to another action to redisplay the form.

Comment: Sorry for such a delay...I believe you are correct but what I had to do was, in my controller, is a '$form->getElement('elementName')->setValue('value');' in order to set the values on most elements. I think it is because of the way I am using the form... which is somewhat non-conventional. If I just plainly 'echo' the entire form, it works fine, but the way I am using it (removing many parts) I had to manually re-populate the form. Fortunately, getting the values is convenient for me though. Thanks for the help!